# Writing nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

From an Organization table two other tables are hanging with `belongs_to` and `has_many` associations, they both have that **organization_id** key.

[image]

So for eager loading I wrote this:

```
@organization = Organization.includes(:population_summaries, :key_performance_inds).find(params[:id])
```

This should work.

But now I have a third table to include in there. **key_performance_interval**  which has that `kpi_id` field that is used as foreign key to point to key_performance_int table. I can't get that part to write and add to my eager loading section.  How should I add that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To included nested associations, you write it as a hash:

```
@organization = Organization.includes([:population_summaries, key_performance_inds:  :key_performance_interval]).find(params[:id])
```

You can read about it on this [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) under section 12.1.2

Comment: thanks, not sure why RubyMine is saying "Extra Call Argument" when I wrote that.

Comment: Are you on ruby 1.8 or 1.9? You might have to use the old style hashes if you're on 1.8.

Comment: I am on 1.9 ,  how about the location of ":" in key_performance_inds   ... your code it is on the right hand side "key_performance_inds:"  , how about if I put the colon on the left like ":key_performance_ind" ?

Comment: Awesome, now RubyMine error is gone. But one question for my learning: Do we need to put all of them in array? or just the one that have "nested hash" ?

Comment: The `#includes` method takes a single argument, which is why the whole thing needs to be passed in as an array.